# Alternative to diode to allow uniform and predictable voltage drops or On resistance

Tags: diodes, multiplexer, ohmmeter

I'm trying to design a relatively high accuracy auto ranging Ohmmeter. A typical Arduino example can be found here:

http://www.circuitstoday.com/ohmmeter-using-arduino

[image: multi-source stimulus for Arduino ohmmeter]

The problem with this design is that it uses Diodes to prevent reverse currents. Now to ensure accuracy the exact Diode drop of each and every Diode needs to be known. Initially I thought I could order a "high tolerance Diode" like you can resistors (0.1% etc) but apparently there is no way to guarantee a diode drop.

My next bright idea was to replace all diodes with an 8 channel multiplexer. I had assumed that the "switch" in the multiplexer had an independent resistance but soon found that the On resistance(Ron) of a multiplexer is dependent on the input voltage of the channel selected. Due to the fact that the circuit is used as a voltage divider and there will always be an unknown resistance, the input voltage to each channel will never be the same and so it seems impossible to know what the Ron would be at any given time.

I'm really hoping someone knows of a simple alternative method/solution? I guess relays are an option but they are bulky and seem like overkill. I'm almost tempted to just use diodes and individually measure the diode drop but that makes reproducibility difficult.

Comment: The answer you may not like: you can't use this approach for more precision measurements. You will need to switch to multiple ranges of precise current sources for your stimulus with the associated complexity. I don't think there's much of a way to calibrate-out the diodes in this design.

Comment: "High accuracy" requires calibration to traceable standards. Do you have access to these? Or do you mean "high precision?" Either way, what are your accuracy and precision requirements for measuring resistance?

Comment: @jonk you're right, Precision. The actual R precision requirements are still to be determined. I will be fabricating a bio-material and tracking a change in R over time, hence the need for autoranging. It is still to be determined what base R the material will be at and by how much it will change. I might have even been a bit bold in saying "High" precision because it's possible the changes are so great that it doesn't matter, but I'm designing for worst case. The bigger issue is that the reading must be stable when switching to the next R range.Did that answer your question?

Comment: Yeah. That helps. What's the likely range of values? How many decades do you think you'll need? From what to what?

Comment: @jonk , like I say I don't know. My previous research on Bacteria had R changes of between 400-1K Ohm with a base R of around 400 Ohm. But my current research is involving viruses and gold coatings which is basically a completely different ball game. I expect the base resistance to drop drastically due to gold being very conductive but guessing a range without experimentation would be a shot in the dark.

Comment: How long do you have to make a single measurement? 10 per second or 10 per hour or?  What's the measurement rate you require? And... well... why aren't you just buying a piece of equipment for this? Isn't a one-off deal? Is this at a university? Or a corporation? Are you intending that others replicate your instrumentation? (Sorry to ask so many questions... but I have them and it seems to influence my thinking.)

Comment: @jonk, Questions are great! I'm a masters student at University. Designing low cost portable electronic biosensors to detect bacteria, viruses etc etc. So to answer your Qus. I think measurements every second(possibly even every 5 seconds if settling time is needed) would be sufficient with initial tests running for a couple of hours (Day?) but ideally actual results would be read in at least 20 minutes. So I'm not buying equipment because they're usually costly and most features are not needed. I have high precision Multimeters in my Lab but they won't be useful for real application. Nick

Comment: That helps a lot. I guess the remaining thing that bothers me is that you haven't or can't, for reasons that aren't clear to me, make measurements using the high precision lab systems to get an idea of the order of resistances. Is it that you can't just go use gold coatings and waste them? Also, given these are viruses... is there a current limit/voltage limit that can be used on them without inducing some unwanted chemical reactions or changing the equilibrium balance of the products? Cripes. All kinds of things are popping to mind that may be problems here. So what's the volt limitation?

Comment: @jonk Yes, so many variables to think about! Um actually i will be using the high precision lab systems for initial testing but only when I have the material fabricated. Waiting for orders from USA for that. So i'm working iteratively, first a generic autoranging system that I can validate using known resistors and POTS, But once I know the specifics I will then fine tune the design. Most research points to Voltage range of 0-5V and a current range of uA to a few mA. I really appreciate your input! Although I knew about the limitations I hadn't quite thought about the implementation just yet.

Comment: I would be concerned about whether you can measure resistance at all in such a system using a DC probe current, as even a tiny current risks causing polarisation or electrochemical reactions. Possibly you should reconsider whether you actually need to build a circuit before you've narrowed down what the measurement needs to be? Otherwise it looks as if you're jumping ahead to considerations of commercial viability before you've done the real research on whether there is anything to commercialise. I did my PhD in biosensing, btw.

Comment: As others said, low Rdson MOSFETS will do a moderately good job if the circuit is designed to suit. | A little known fact is that the saturation voltage of bipolar transistors tends to keep dropping as drive current is increased. I long ago used low cost TO92 bipolars with forced betas of 10+ to get good enough results in a circuit similar in concept to yours. ie for say 0.1 mA collector current I used 1 mA or more of base drive. Normally that makes no sense - here where Vsat is the key issue, it does. Nowadays I'd probably use a MOSFET.

Comment: @nekomatic We have already validated that you can in fact measure a DC resistance of bacteria. Electrochemical reactions are an issue but we have determined that positive detection has a much greater effect. I'm not really thinking of commercialization, but rather we are focusing on finding cheaper methods that are more accessible to third world countries(South Africa). Research does show promise that DC electrochemical changes can be detected but resistance is not well studied. other options are Voltammetry and EIS. I'd be interested in reading your PhD if it's available online?

Comment: @NickLaw If the DC measurement is reliable and reproducible, great. By 'commercialisation' I guess I mean that designing a circuit to make a specified measurement within a target production cost feels like more of an implementation issue, requiring only a predictable expenditure on engineering, than a research question. PhD not online, sorry, but it was on immobilising biomolecules using electropolymerisation (and produced no publications...)

Answer (score 2):

To expand a bit on the comments. By ordinary DMM standards, it will take an enormous amount of work to get anything like "precision" out of this circuit. The most important factor is one which is not addressed: the Arduino digital outputs are hardly precision voltage sources. Without knowing those voltages there is no way to tell (with any precision) what the resistance is.

Second, even if all your diodes are identical, their voltage will change with current, which means that you need to calibrate all your channels. Voltage drop on the active diode will change with the value of the resistance being measured.

Third, while this is probably unnoticeable at the scale you're working, for a given current the diode voltage will vary with temperature, and that includes temperature changes caused by self-heating.

So perhaps you should define "precision", along with "accuracy" - they are not the same, after all. The circuit strikes me as the work of someone not very knowledgeable about electronics who had "this great idea", and who is demonstrating that when your only tool is a hammer, all your problems look like nails.

EDIT - An alternative would be to use p-type MOSFETs as isolators rather than diodes. This would look like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx4z6o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

with a couple of notes. First, the 5 volts is not the Arduino power supply. It is a separately derived, stable and accurate 5 volts. Second, the gates of the FETs are driven by the Arduino, and their polarities are reversed from your nominal circuit. That is, a HIGH disables a resistor, while a LOW drives it to +5. Third, the FETs should be logic-level FETs. "Regular" FETs are typically not guaranteed to turn on fully with 5 volts on the gate (although they usually will. Sort of).

Comment: Thanks! I fully agree with you! I'm using the Arduino for proof of concept and then upgrading when I know exactly what I want(results of tests may indicate need for more complex analysis like EIS or Voltammetry). Your second point: calibrate all the channels? can you explain? and yes I agree with you on the link, I don't agree with half of what they did (especially the code), I figured I'd use it as a base and work my way up to a better design. But if you know of any better schematics or links I'm more than willing to re-design?

Comment: Calibrate all the channels. If the 1k resistor feeds a 1k unknown, the resulting voltage across D3 will be different than the voltage across D4 when the unknown is resistor is 2.2k. Each channel is a resistor/diode driven high when the others are driven low. Since each has a different current, each will have different diode voltages when near optimum. For what it's worth, you should be able to get 1% resolution, but that assumes a precision voltage supply for the Arduino, AND very consistent behavior of the digital outputs. And you still haven't stated your requirements.

Comment: @NickLaw - See edit.

Comment: Awesome! that actually makes a lot of sense! I'm gonna have to brush up on my MOSFETs theory, I'm wondering if the MOSFETs would need to be calibrated, like the diodes? But if MOSFETs are like BJTs I'm thinking the current and Vds will be equal across all channels. Regarding the requirements. Did you see the comment to Jonk? Basically The requirements are still to be determined by a bio-material that has not yet been manufactured. It really depends on the initial Resistive base and then the overall change in resistance over a period of time.

Comment: @NickLaw - As long as Rds(on) is less than about 0.5% of the reference resistor, its error contribution will be less than the errors caused by the 10 bit ADC in the Arduino. For the resistor values you're usiing, this should not remotely be a problem. Plus, of course, your resistor tolerances will probably be 1%, which puts a 1% limit on your meaurement accuracy, so Rds is almost certainly not a problem. You need to do the calculations to get a feel for your error limits. Calculate voltages assuming errors in supply voltage, and resistor errors.

Comment: Awesome! I think I'm gonna run with your idea and see if I can get something going! Thanks for the input.